# How can I load this JSON in a dataframe?

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, dataframe

Trying to read the following JSON file in Python:

```
[[ {"fecha" : "2013-01-01","indicativo" : "3195","nombre" : "MADRID, RETIRO","provincia" : "MADRID","altitud" : "667","tmed" : "6,4","prec" :"0,0"},{"fecha" : "2013-01-02","indicativo" : "3196","nombre" : "MADRID,RETIRO","provincia" : "MADRID","altitud" : "667","tmed" : "6,5","prec" : "0,0"},{"fecha" : "2013-01-03","indicativo" : "3197","nombre": "MADRID, RETIRO","provincia" : "MADRID","altitud" : "667","tmed" : "6,7","prec" : "0,0"}],[ {"fecha" : "2013-02-01","indicativo" : "3195","nombre" : "MADRID, RETIRO","provincia" : "MADRID","altitud" : "667","tmed" : "6,4","prec" : "0,0"},{"fecha" : "2013-02-02","indicativo" :"3196","nombre" : "MADRID, RETIRO","provincia" : "MADRID","altitud" : "667","tmed" : "6,5","prec" : "0,0"}]]
```

I have tried the following options:

option 1:

```
df2 = pd.read_json('test.json',orient='split')
```

result:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'iteritems'
```

option 2:

```
df2 = pd.read_json('test.json',orient='columns')
```

result:
[image: result 2]

The expected result I want is:

[image]

Basically a dataframe flatenned, with columns names = attributes and onw row per each element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can try this piece of code:

```
import pandas as pd
import json


file = './test.json'

with open(file, 'r') as f:
    data = json.load(f)


big_df = pd.DataFrame()

for i in range(len(data)):
    a = json.dumps(data[i])
    big_df = pd.concat([big_df, pd.read_json(a)], axis=0)

big_df.reset_index(drop=True)
```

*Caveat*: I have tested the code in `python3`, but I think it should work in `python2`, as well.

Answer (score 0):

The pd.DataFrame constructor can take a list of dictionaries as input, so the solution is simply:

```
import pandas as pd    
import json

file = 'test.json'
with open(file, 'r') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
rows = data[0]
df = pd.DataFrame(rows)
```

If you want to know the correct format of the pd.read_json() input, take a look at df.to_json().

Comment: If I execute : df6=pd.DataFrame(df2[0][0]) then I retrieve the error: ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index